# Hadoop sort and group keys differently

Tags: mapreduce, hadoop2, comparator

I am doing a word count, so the mapper returns key and value pairs

```
zz 1
zz 1 
b 1
c 1
```

and my reducer adds them up together

```
b 1
c 1
zz 2
```

but I want the keys to be sorted by length (decreasing)

```
zz 2
b 1
c 1
```

So I create a Comparator for the word length

```
public static class LengthComparator extends WritableComparator {
    @Override
    @Override
    public int compare(WritableComparable a, WritableComparable b) {
        String w1 = a.toString();
        String w2 = b.toString();

        if (w1.length == w2.length) return 0;

        return w1.length() > w2.length() ? -1 : 1;
    }
}
```

then set with

```
 job.setSortComparatorClass(LengthComparator.class);
```

now my output is this

```
 zz 2
 b 2
```

so i try this

```
public static class LengthComparator extends WritableComparator {
    @Override
    @Override
    public int compare(WritableComparable a, WritableComparable b) {
        String w1 = a.toString();
        String w2 = b.toString();

        return w1.length() > w2.length() ? -1 : 1;
    }
}
```

now my output is

```
 zz 1
 zz 1
 b 1
 c 1
```

How do I make it such that the keys are grouped by the key but the output is sorted by the length of the word?

Comment: First compare by key length. If they are equal, then compare keys lexicographically.

Comment: @gudok it seems to work thanks